# Random crashes when using androidx.navigation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

while using

```
'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0' 
'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0'
```

the app works normally for some time until randomly i start getting

```
 Navigation action/destination cannot be found from the current destination NavGraph
```

when i click on any button that trigger a navigation, i use navigation like this

```
//to navigate 
var dir = MainMenuDirections.actionMainMenuToSelectPayments()
NavHostFragment.findNavController(this).navigate(dir)

//to pop current fragment
NavHostFragment.findNavController(this).popBackStack()
```

i tried using version 2.2.0

apparently this is a bug present since version 1.0.0 alpha 4 and it happens when you call Navigate() after calling popBackStack(), so weird how is everyone using this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer I get from the issue tracker if anyone makes the mistakes I made**

This is a similar case as b/128734685 where `nav.popBackStack()` returning false means still removes your login2 from the back stack.

That's why the error message says:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination com.dzdoes.i.payments:id/action_login2_to_registre cannot be found from the current destination NavGraph(com.dzdoes.i.payments:id/nav_graph) startDestination={Destination(com.dzdoes.i.payments:id/login2) label=Login class=com.dzdoes.i.payments.ui.Auth.Login}
Correctly indicating that you are not on the login2 destination (you are on the root nav_graph, which correctly does not have an action named action_login2_to_registre).
```

This is the intended behavior and, as mentioned on the other issue, the only reason you still see your fragment on the screen is to allow the activity animation to complete with the fragment still visible (rather than animating an empty activity).

You have two options:

Stop overriding `onBackPressed()`. Instead, you should follow the provide custom back navigation and register your own `OnBackPressedCallback` callback at the activity level with no `LifecycleOwner`. This will ensure that it is only triggered when there is no Navigation back stack:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    ...

    onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
            val builder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this@NavHostAuth)
            builder
                .setMessage("are you sure you want to exit")
                .setPositiveButton("yes") { _, _ -> finish() }
                .setNegativeButton("no") { _, _ -> }
                .show()
        }
    })
}
```

Note that you'll need to add `app:defaultNavHost="true"` to your XML as that is what causes `NavHostFragment` to correctly intercept the back button by default. This is the recommended way of achieving this functionality.

Update your `setNegativeButton` to navigate to your starting destination again.

```
.setNegativeButton(
    "no",
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which -> nav.navigate(R.id.login2) })
```

Note that in either case, you don't ever need to call `dialog.dismiss()` from your `setNegativeButton` listener - the `AlertDialog` is automatically dismissed whenever the positive or negative button is pressed.

Comment: haven't figured why, but I'm getting this crash with after `popUpToInclusive = true`

Comment: because you have no fragment left in the stack, popUpToInclusive = true will also remove the target fragment, it may be visible but it is not in the stack, so you are not in the source fragment that you want to execute the navigation from